Error "address already in use" when trying to connect to google cloud SQL using cloud-sql-connector
THE PROBLEM
When trying to connect to my cloud SQL database, I'm getting the following error.
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use /Users/josechavez/projectName/projectName/.s.PGSQL.5432
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1812:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1877:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1976:5)
at node:internal/util:410:7
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Server.<anonymous> (node:internal/util:396:12)
at Connector.startLocalProxy (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector/dist/mjs/connector.js:207:22)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async connect (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/lib/connect.ts:16:5)
at async prismaClientSingleton (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/lib/prisma.ts:17:16) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',

   errno: -48,
   syscall: 'listen',
   address: '/Users/josechavez/projectName/projectName/.s.PGSQL.5432',
   port: -1
}

I'm confident that all the previous steps, like authentication and configuration, are correct. But this error has no documentation or possible solutions.
I've tried with 5432, 5433, ... and so on. but nothing still.
This is how I'm connecting my NextJS app to my cloudSQL database
I've also tried to use this whole path that is mentioned in the docs /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432
But this time I get an error that says no access/view permissions, but I'm not sure if this is the way.
Someone please help me, Thanks in advance!

Do you start manually and externally to your app the Cloud SQL proxy?

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but yeah, for now I'm starting my app in local, using the library recommended by google , which starts the connection. My SQL instance is up and running, I think that that means it is 'started'. Or am I missing any config step ?

Ok, my question was: so you start the cloud-sql-proxy binary on your computer in addition to your application?

@guillaumeblaquiere no, I don't start any binary. should I? I'm on a Mac, and what I understood from the documentation is that these libraries automatically connects and authenticate based on the login I did on the google CLI.

Did you try to delete the file /Users/josechavez/projectName/projectName/.s.PGSQL.5432, if exists?

As described in the following issue. The error was indeed because of the file that was being generated. That file must be deleted before trying again.
Anyways, This is the core problem I was facing, in case someone is interested, which is related to this question
